QNetworkAccessManager GET. Qt application console. Wireshark does not show traffic
I'm trying to get relay status for ADAM device from my Qt app. Everything seems to be working well if I run the following GET in Postman:



Wireshark shows the trace correctly:

But it does not work from my Qt application. I use QNetworkAccessManager and my code looks like this:
_networkAccessManagerPtr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(_networkAccessManagerPtr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)), Qt::DirectConnection);

SLOT:
void TestClass::ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        qWarning() << "ERROR:" << reply->errorString();
        return;
    }
}

GET method:
bool TestClass::Get()
{
    bool aResult = false;

    QString _completeUrl = QString().append("http://").append(_ipAddress.c_str()).append(":").append(QString::number(_port)).append(URL_LOGIN.c_str());

    QString _auth = QString().append(_username.c_str()).append(":").append(_password.c_str());

    QString _headerData = QString().append("Basic ").append(_auth.toLocal8Bit().toBase64());

    _request.setUrl(QUrl(_completeUrl));
    _request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    _request.setRawHeader("Authorization", _headerData.toLocal8Bit());

    QNetworkReply * _replyPtr = _networkAccessManagerPtr->get(_request);

    _replyPtr->waitForReadyRead(-1);

    aResult = ( _replyPtr->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute ).toInt() == 200 );

    if ( !aResult )
    {
        _status = DeviceStatus::DEVICE_UNRESPONSIVE;

        qDebug() << _replyPtr->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute ).toString();
    }
    else
    {
        _status = DeviceStatus::EVERYTHING_OK;
    }

    _replyPtr->deleteLater();

    return aResult;
}

Slot does not work, aResult=false and Wireshark does not show anything and I do not why...

OT: Don't use the SIGNAL and SLOT macros in new code.

waitForReadyRead does nothing for a QNetworkReply. You need to let the event loop run its course. This is typically done by creating a nested event loop and tying the finished signal to its exit member.

OT: setting content-type on a GET is weird. Did you mean to set Accept instead?

Final OT: QString::arg is your friend for constructing strings from pieces.

Ok. I have done these changes but I do not receive anything in wireshark...

Edit your question.
